# Upload Zip file in PHP

Tags: php, upload, zip

I want to upload a zip file and extract it to a folder using php. I am using this code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;              
if ($zip->open($filename) == TRUE){                     
     $zip->extractTo('Articles/');          
     $zip->close();                     
     $isql="update articles set a_file='$newfile' where a_id='$fpk'"; 
     $urec=mysql_query($isql);                                          
} 
else {                  
     echo 'failed';                 
}
```

But it is showing these warnings:

> Warning: ZipArchive::extractTo() [ziparchive.extractto]: Invalid or
>   unitialized Zip object in D:\xampp\htdocs\Constructor\adminhome.php on
>   line 36
>
> Warning: ZipArchive::close() [ziparchive.close]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object in D:\xampp\htdocs\Constructor\adminhome.php on
>   line 37...

Shall I include the ziparchive library? If yes then how could I do this?

Comment: I think here is the mistake $zip = new ZipArchive();

Comment: Have you handled the file upload in HP and use `move_uploaded_file()` to move the file into the file system before attempting to open it?

Comment: no,i did not.i thought that it will upload and extract the files automatically...i think it the problem..

Comment: You must have ZipArchive installed or you would have hit an error earlier.  Have you checked that $filename actually exists?

Comment: thanx Mike W.That was the problem.its done successfully.I just forgot to upload the file before extracting it.thats why the problem occured..

Answer (score 0):

you should check if open method is returning TRUE with === (with type check), otherwise some error code returned from open method could evaluate to TRUE.

For instalation please folow [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php)

Comment: actually i did not upload the file before extracting it.thats why the problem occured.now it solved.thanx.

Answer (score 0):

```
Basically problem in our open method use bellow code 

$opened = $zip->open( $filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE );

I think you are using php 5.2.8 it does not work and gives this warning:
```

Comment: actually i did not upload the file before extracting it.thats why the problem occured.now it solved.thanx.